# Multiple file input validation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created simple logic where on change input function starts to validate input file but its showing **ReferenceError: validateImage is not defined**

```js
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       function validateImage(id) {
          var formData = new FormData();
 
          var file = document.getElementById(id).files[0];
 
          formData.append("Filedata", file);
          var t = file.type.split('/').pop().toLowerCase();
          if (t != "jpeg" && t != "jpg" && t != "png" && t != "bmp" && t != "gif") {
            alert('Please select a valid image file');
            document.getElementById(id).value = '';
            return false;
          }
          if (file.size > 1024000) {
            alert('Max Upload size is 1MB only');
            document.getElementById(id).value = '';
            return false;
          }
        return true;
       }
</script>
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUploadFile">  
 <label>Select single file to upload:</label><br/>
 <input type="file" name="files[]" id="img1" onchange="validateImage('img1')" /><br/>
 <input type="file" name="files[]" id="img2" onchange="validateImage('img2')" /><br/>
 <input type="file" name="files[]" id="img3" onchange="validateImage('img3')" /><br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you have wrapped fucntion inside  $(document).ready(function(){.so you cannot access it from outside

Comment: switch the function out of document.ready() and it will be visible

Comment: Thanks a lot @MadhawaPriyashantha thats the answer i was looking , work load makes us blind we cant even see small things then we find heroes like you who save us from embarrassment . Again thank you very much for quick help

Comment: @Satya Thanks bro for help , have a great day ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fucntion wrapped inside $(document).ready(function(){.so you cannot access it from outside so switch the function out of document.ready() and it will be visible 
Thanks to 
 @Madhawa Priyashantha & @Satya

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   }

   function validateImage(id) {
            var formData = new FormData();

            var file = document.getElementById(id).files[0];

            formData.append("Filedata", file);
            var t = file.type.split('/').pop().toLowerCase();
            if (t != "jpeg" && t != "jpg" && t != "png" && t != "bmp" && t != "gif") {
                alert('Please select a valid image file');
                document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                return false;
            }
            if (file.size > 1024000) {
                alert('Max Upload size is 1MB only');
                document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line:

`window.validateImage = validateImage`

before the script closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

you have declare a validateImage function inside a function so globally so you cannot access it from global scope. You have to declare it in a global scope. For that simply declare validateImage function outside ready function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   }

   function validateImage(id) {
            var formData = new FormData();

            var file = document.getElementById(id).files[0];

            formData.append("Filedata", file);
            var t = file.type.split('/').pop().toLowerCase();
            if (t != "jpeg" && t != "jpg" && t != "png" && t != "bmp" && t != "gif") {
                alert('Please select a valid image file');
                document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                return false;
            }
            if (file.size > 1024000) {
                alert('Max Upload size is 1MB only');
                document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
```